# Setting an item to localStorage from one window and getting it immediately from another window fails in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, local-storage

I'm using localStorage on IE8. I'm setting a value in a popup window and then calls a function on the opener window, where I'm trying to get the value from localStorage.

It appears that the value is not there. If I add a timeout of 1 second before trying to read it, the value seems to be there.

Is that a known behaviour of localStorage? If so, what is the appropriate way to handle it?

I didn't encounter that on other browsers, should I expect this also on other browsers?

**The code:**

Popup:

```
localStorage.setItem('myToken', token)
```

Main window:

```
localStorage.getItem('myToken');
```

Comment: It is a normal behaviour of IE. When weird errors happen in IE, add a setTimeout. However show the code

Comment: Thanks. I'll add the relevant code sections to the question.

Comment: I call `setItem` in the popup before calling the opener window (which leads to calling `getItem`) and then close the popup (which does not seem related since it doesn't work also if I keep the popup opened). When I added 300ms delay before reading in the main window, the value is present. However, just adding this timeout doesn't feel like a robust solution...

Comment: The question that comes to my mind is why call set from the window and get from the opener? Do the setting from the opener with `opener.someFunction()`

Comment: The reason is that I run a flow in the popup at the end of which I get the value which I need to save. The simplest thing was to immediately save it in the popup code. The problem only appeared when I tested on IE8. Your suggestion is perfectly valid. Thanks.